# Could not open include file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I'm have a visual studio 2010 c++ solution, and there is an include that fails on compile (Fatal error, could not open include file).

My problem is: The path is specified in C/C++ Addition Include Directories, and I've run out of ideas... I know it's probably a simple thing but any hints at all would be great !

Also, does the fact that my project is on the desktop could cause a problem ?

Thanks

EDIT:

The header file is here C:\users\test\Desktop\testProject\mainLib\lib\common.h
I include this in the additionnal directories : "C:\users\test\Desktop\testProject\

and my include looks like this :

```
#include <mainLib\lib\common.h>
```

common.h is a header that I've created

Comment: If VS can't find your include files, it's that your paths are wrong. We can't help you with the information you posted.

Comment: Do you know of the distinction between `#include <...>` and `#include "..."`? Which one do you use? Why? _Edit:_ Since this now provides the data needed to answer the question, ___please do not vote to close this___.

Comment: #include" " start by looking locally and #include< > just go with the additionnal directories ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerous possibilities.

If you have

```
c:\demo\include\sub\this.hpp
```

You should have

```
#include <sub/this.hpp> // with "c:\demo\include" in additional includes
```

---

If you have

```
c:\demo2\test.cpp
c:\demo2\test.hpp
```

you should have, in test.cpp

```
#include "test.hpp" // NOT <test.hpp>
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: If you're going to use the angle brackets, the include paths should be in the `PATH` environment variable on VS10.